# Отсортировать строки по количеству символов в них с выдачей значений Python

Tags: python, pandas

Есть следующий столбец:

```
TesT
Hello
Hello w
Hello wo
```

Необходимо посчитать количество символом (можно вместе в пропусками) , вывести числа в соседнем столбце и отсортировать, самые длинные сверху.То есть на выходе необходимо получить:

```
TesT        Value   Rating
Hello wo    7       1
Hello w     6       2
Hello       5       3
```

Comment: ну и какие вы приложили усилия?
что не получается?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример:

```
res = (d.assign(Value=d["TesT"].str.len())
        .sort_values("Value", ascending=False)
        .assign(Rating=np.arange(1, len(d)+1))
        .reset_index(drop=True))
```

результат:

```
In [41]: res
Out[41]:
       TesT  Value  Rating
0  Hello wo      8       1
1   Hello w      7       2
2     Hello      5       3
```

Answer (score 3):

pd.Series.str.len вернет длину строк, сортируем по ней по убыванию и берем index+1  в качестве рейтинга

```
df.assign(Value=lambda x: x['TesT'].str.len()).sort_values('Value', ascending=False) \
  .reset_index(drop=True).assign(Rating=df.index+1)

       TesT  Value  Rating
0  Hello wo      8       1
1   Hello w      7       2
2     Hello      5       3
```